# react createRef keeps returning null

Tags: reactjs

I have a ref:

```
const ref = React.createRef();
```

I pass it like so:

```
<WinnerPopup winner={turn ? 'cross' : 'circle'} ref={ref}></WinnerPopup>
```

This is the component:

```
const WinnerPopup = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <Popup
        trigger={<button ref={ref} className="button"></button>}
        modal
        nested
    >
        {close => (
            <div className="modal">
                <button className="close" onClick={close}>
                    &times;
                </button>
                <div className="header"> We have a winner! </div>
                <div className="content">
                    {`Winner is ${props.winner}`}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </Popup>
));
```

And I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

This is such a simple use case and almost exactly the same thing as the document so I cannot figure out why I can't access the button.

Comment: how is `trigger` used inside `<Popup>`?

Comment: its a jsx element thats rendered first, when you click it the popup pops https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-popup

Answer (score 2):

I think you [normally use forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) when you want to pass along the ref to the outer most component of what you are wrapping with forwardRef... ie. you create a  that is a wrapper around  so you forward the ref onto the  ... in this case you are passing it to the button you are passing into a prop (trigger) of your outer most component... maybe you want to just pass the reference in a custom prop, like "triggerButtonRef"... also, what purpose do you need the ref on that button?

You might try and pass the ref as a custom prop, instead of trying to use forwardRef, like:

```js
<WinnerPopup winner={turn ? 'cross' : 'circle'} triggerRef={ref} />

const WinnerPopup = ({ triggerRef, winner }) => (
    <Popup
        trigger={<button ref={triggerRef} className="button"></button>}
        modal
        nested
    >
        {close => (
            <div className="modal">
                <button className="close" onClick={close}>
                    &times;
                </button>
                <div className="header"> We have a winner! </div>
                <div className="content">
                    {`Winner is ${winner}`}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </Popup>
);
```

Depending on how `<WinnerPopup />` works and/or if that is also your own custom component, AND you want to be able to control if it's open from the parent or another component, I think a better solution might be to store a state variable to control whether or not the popup is open, for instance:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const onClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <SomeOtherButton onClick={onClick} />
      <WinnerPopup winner={turn ? 'cross' : 'circle'} isOpen={open} />
    </>
  )
}

const WinnerPopup = ({ isOpen, winner }) => (
    <Popup
        trigger={<button className="button"></button>}
        modal
        nested
        open={isOpen}
    >
        {close => (
            <div className="modal">
                <button className="close" onClick={close}>
                    &times;
                </button>
                <div className="header"> We have a winner! </div>
                <div className="content">
                    {`Winner is ${winner}`}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </Popup>
);
```

Comment: I want to trigger a click on the button inside the component when a certain condition is met. Also, can you add a small example because I am not sure how to do the custom prop suggestion? @andersryanc

Comment: if you are trying to change state and force the popup to open, more commonly, I would suggest passing down a prop to Popup directly... so, it kinda depends on how Popup works...